# Show that $\max f(x)$ = $\min\Big(- \log f(x)\Big)$

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Assume that $f : \mathbb R ^D \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a function with $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in\mathbb R^D$.
>   Further, assume that $f$ has a well-defined maximum value, *i.e.* there exists a point $x^\ast \in \mathbb R^D$ such that $f(x) \leq f(x^*)$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb R^D$. Argue why
>
> $$\max f(x) = \min  \Big(-\log f (x)\Big)$$
>
> where log: $\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is the natural logarithm.

I've come so far that I have to differentiate $f(x)$ and $-\log(x)$, and set the equal to $0$, then show that they have the same zero points, and afterwards differentiate once more to see if it is a min or max, however once I tried to do that with a random $f(x)$ function, I got different $0$ values, so is my approach wrong?

I think my problem more concretely is, how do I differentiate a function $f(x)$ I don't know?

Comment: `how do i differentiate` You don't. The problem says nothing about the differentiability of $f(x)$, so you can't assume it is differentiable.

Comment: Is the equality $\max f(x) = \min  \Big(-\log f (x)\Big)$ really correct? Shouldn't there be $\log$ somewhere on the left hand side too?

Comment: Do you mean $\arg \max f(x) = \arg \min (- \log f(x))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log$ is an increasing function. This means that $x<y \iff \log(x)<\log(y)$ (whenever $\log(x)$ and $\log(y)$ are defined). So therefore $-\log$ is a decreasing function, which means that $f(x) < f(x^*) \iff -\log(f(x)) > -\log(f(x^*).$

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\frac{d}{dx} [-\log f(x)] = -\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)},
$$
it is easy to see that if $df/dx = 0$ in $x=x_0$, then $-d/dx\log f(x) = 0$. Differentiating again:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} [-\log f(x)] = \frac{f'(x)^2-f(x) f''(x)}{f(x)^2}
$$
Then, since $f'(x)=0$ in $x=x_0$:
$$
\left. \frac{d^2}{dx^2} [-\log f(x)] \right|_{x=x_0} = -\frac{f''(x_0)}{f(x_0)}.
$$
If $x=x_0$ is a maximum of $f(x)$, then $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0)<0$. Then, $$
\left. \frac{d^2}{dx^2} [-\log f(x)] \right|_{x=x_0}
$$
is greater then $0$, and $x_0$ is a point of minimum of $\log f(x)$.

Naturally, those results stands only if $f(x_0)\neq 0$ and if $f'(x_0)$ exists (as pointed by dxiv and holo - thanks).

Comment: `those results stands only if` ...only if $f$ is differentiable, which is not given.

Comment: Why did you assume that $\dfrac{df}{dx}$ exist?

Comment: I'm an engineer, we do this all the time XD...
Seriously, there is some reason for which I should not assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$? It's because the demonstration must hold for a more generic or strong case?

Comment: @rafa11111 the reason is that not all functions are differentiable everywhere, or even somewhere, so yes, because the statement is stronger

Comment: @rafa11111 You can't just assume something that the problem doesn't have as a premise. For an engineering example, consider a [sawtooth-like function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave) defined on a suitable interval. The statement of the problem holds true, but your proof thereof fails badly.